# Cómo cambiar ruta ejecutable en Nebeans (C++)

Tags: netbeans, rutas, exe, makefile, ejecutar

Cómo se puede cambiar en el IDE Netbeans la ruta que tiene que tomar para encontrar el ejecutable?, en mi caso, al ejecutar, solo me acepta el fichero de nombre `main.exe`(así se llama en mi proyecto), yo creo saber si hay una herramienta en este programa que me permita ponerle otro nombre al ejecutable, por ejemplo un fichero de nombre `main`, ahora mismo no puedo hacer eso simplemente cambiando el nombre en el Makefile, si dejo de poner `main.exe` ya no me deja ejecutar.

Quiero puntualizar que mi proyecto en Netbeans no lo creé en el IDE, sino que lo importé.

Gracias

Comment: Al importar, ¿desde dónde lo importaste?

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos Desde una carpeta en el escritorio donde lo tenía guardado